# Yandex, Google индексирет непонятные ссылки

Tags: nginx, seo, поисковые-системы

Я написал логи индексирования записывающие какой бот на какую страницу заходил (чтобы не было лишних вопросов)

И постоянно замечаю что Google, Yandex бот заходят на такие ссылки

```
https://site.ru/?C=N;O=D
https://site.ru/?C=S;O=A
```

Но что это за ссылки? Обычно эти `GET` параметры меняют своё содержимое, сайт писал лично, и такого там не предусмотрено, сайт полностью чист и не имеет вредоносного кода при переходе по ссылке тоже самое что и `https://site.ru/` так как параметры негде не используются, сервер на `nginx` возможно проблема в нем?

А также на сайте есть профили пользователей, ссылки на них `https://site.ru/uidТУТНОМЕРINT`, они открыты для индексации, но были случаи что yandex переходил по ссылки которые не существует, к примеру юзеров только 6 а он заходит эж на `https://site.ru/uid127`

Comment: Может кто-то ссылается на эти страницы? Проверьте в ГуглАналитикс или в Яндекс.Метрике, где источник.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#query

Comment: Но у меня nginx да и все директории полностью стоят deny from all

Comment: @RedWoolf, последний комментарий адресован мне? если да, то я всего лишь ответил на вопрос «но что это за ссылки?» // в *nginx*, кстати, насколько мне известно, данную функциональность не реализовывали за ненадобностью.